# Linux script to automatically convert file type to UTF8

Tags: linux, shell, utf-8

I am in a tight spot and could use some help coming up with a linux shell script to convert a directory full of pipes delimited files from their original file encoding to UTF-8.  The source files are either US-ASCII or ISO-8859-1 file encoding.  The closest thing that I could come up with is:

```
iconv -f ISO8859-1 -t utf-8 * > name_of_utf8_file
```

This condenses all of the files into a single file which is not needed but OK for this application.  The problem is that I neeed to specify both the source and destination file encoding, so for half of the files I don't know what it does.  Is there way to write a shell script using commands like `file -i` or the like.

Any advice here is much appreciated.

Comment: Any ASCII file is already both a valid UTF-8 and a valid ISO-8859-1 file. Conversion to either is a no-op.

Comment: Try using `gfind` for finding your files and executing the conversion using `iconv` for each.

Comment: @Deduplicator The problem is that an ISO-8859-1 file is not a valid UTF-8 file.  UTF-8 is the desired file type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is, (not properly tested, caveat emptor :)), one way of doing it:

Maybe try w/ a small subset first - this is more of a thought example than a turn-key solution.

```
for i in *
do 
  if $( file -i "${i}"|grep -q us-ascii ); then 
    iconv -f us-ascii -t utf-8 "$i" > "${i}.utf8"
  fi 
  if $( file -i "${i}"|grep -q iso-8859-1 ); then 
    iconv -f iso8859-1 -t utf-8 "$i" > "${i}.utf8"
  fi 
done
```